# MySql View - show data from another column in same table

Tags: mysql, view

I have this MySql View definition (done by using Navicat):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
auctions.timelive AS timelive,
selections.id AS sel_id,
auctions.title AS `match`,
selections.title AS selection,
selections.odds AS odds,
auctions.bidprice AS bidprice,
(`auctions`.`bidprice` * (`selections`.`odds` - 1)) AS `next win rise`,
Sum((`auctions`.`bidprice` * (`selections`.`odds` - 1))) AS `pure winnings`,
selections.startamount AS startamount,
(sum((`auctions`.`bidprice` * (`bids`.`odds` - 1))) + `selections`.`startamount`) AS     `winnings with startamount`,
bids.`timestamp` AS `last bid on`,
Max(bids.id) AS `highest bid id`
from (((`bids` join `selections` on((`bids`.`selectionid` = `selections`.`id`))) join   `auctions` on((`bids`.`auctionid` = `auctions`.`id`))) join `users` on((`bids`.`userid` =  `users`.`id`)))
GROUP BY
selections.id,
bids.auctionid
ORDER BY
`last bid on` ASC
```

This is working ok, but now further beside last 'highest bid id' column want to get one more column in this view 'bids.userid' which is basically just right of the column 'highest bid id'.
How to do that? Canot find solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
...
Max(bids.id) AS `highest bid id`
,bids.`userid`
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add this
from ...
```

Comment: it is not showing the correct results. Those data under userid are not those (and only those) which are in bids.userid beside bids.id (only where is those single maximum number)